# Pyinput is showing warning in code but showing error while running the code

Tags: python-3.x

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\encur\Python\os.py", line 5, in 
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput'

Answer (score 0):

The error states that you do not have `pynput` package installed.
To install pyinput, use the following command on your terminal/shell:

```
pip install pynput
```

Or refer to the pypi package page: https://pypi.org/project/pynput/